# How to Select row with maximum date

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my table name tblPE

```
PEID |idnum  | PE_DATE_EXAM   | ATTENDANCE       
1    | 39    | 2014-08-01     | PRESENT       
2    | 42    | 2014-08-10     | ABSENT            
3    | 39    | 2014-08-12     | PRESENT           
4    | 43    | 2014-08-05     | PRESENT        
5    | 42    | 2014-07-15     | NULL           
6    | 39    | 2014-07-03     | ABSENT       
7    | 41    | 2014-08-01     | PRESENT
```

i want to select the maximum PE_DATE_EXAM value where idnum = 39 and ATTENDANCE=PReSENT

the result should be:

```
PEID |idnum  | PE_DATE_EXAM   | ATTENDANCE
-------------------------------------------
3    | 39    | 2014-08-12     | PRESENT
```

Answer (score 5):

For a single record return you can use `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT * FROM tblPE t
WHERE t.idnum = 39 AND t.ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT'
ORDER BY t.PE_DATE_EXAM DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want it dynamic for all `idnum`'s , you can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM tblPE t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblPE s
                 WHERE t.idnum = s.idnum AND s.ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT')
  AND t.attendance = 'PRESENT'
```

Comment: Accidentally you put `ORDER BY t.PE_DATE_EXAM DESC` before `WHERE ..`

Comment: i did waht u said but it got error..

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT * FROM tblPE t ORDER BY t.PE_DATE_EXAM DESC WHERE t.idnum = 39 AND t.ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT' LIMIT 1






 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t.idnum =39 AND t.ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT'

LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated subquery to find the max dates for specific id(s). I personally find this to be more readable and much more straightforward. Also, this approach is typically language agnostic (assuming we are referring to relational SQL databases)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPE t1
WHERE t1.Date = (
                 SELECT MAX(Date)
                 FROM tblPE t2
                 WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
                )
AND t1.Id = 39;
```

Comment: Yep, But it's just a bit slower than an uncorrelated query

Comment: @Strawberry true, you do take a bit of a performance hit, that's a good thing to point out! In my experience it only really becomes painful when you start to reach a fairly large data set size. But for small/medium size data sets, one should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution:

```
SELECT PEID, idnum, PE_DATE_EXAM, ATTENDANCE
FROM tblPE
WHERE idnum = 39 AND ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT' AND PE_DATE_EXAM in (
   SELECT MAX(PE_DATE_EXAM)
   FROM tblPE
   WHERE idnum = 39 AND ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT top 1 * FROM tblPE t
  WHERE t.idnum = 39 AND t.ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT' ORDER BY t.PE_DATE_EXAM DESC;
```

Comment: `TOP 1` Is SQL-Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
select PEID,IDNUM,PE_DATE_EXAM,ATTENDANCE
from
(select PEID,IDNUM,PE_DATE_EXAM,ATTENDANCE,dense_rank() over(order by PE_DATE_EXAM desc) rnum
from TBLPE
order by PE_DATE_EXAM desc)
where rnum = '1';
```

This query is written based on your query result. If you need any clarifications let me know.