# getting value of some columns in a rows selected with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

[image]

The above are my records in a table.

My username is CHIEFME and I can only select the rows `Uploaded By` CHIEFME.

If I select other rows it will pop up a alert box saying that I can only select records uploaded by me.

This is my sample codeine 
[image]

Comment: Can you please add code so we can help you?

Comment: Did your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973527/how-to-select-row-with-maximum-date) question didn't get a correct answer? You scratch our backs, and we'll scratch yours. This is how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: Match the id of logged in user and that row id if differ then show alert

Comment: above is the sample code.. thanks in advance..

Comment: Only in unique situations pictures are wanted, not for the entire question. If the link dies this question is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop the rows in table at first  check if logged user name is not the name of the user that added this record:

```
<?php
 // .... your code here
<td align...> <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" ($loggedUsername !== $row[username] ? readonly : "")>... </td>

// or

<td align... < input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" ($loggedUsername !== $row[username] ? "onclick=\"alert(this is not added by you!); return;\"" : "") >... </td>
```

Then in client use javascript or jQuery to check if the user click on readonly checkbox:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox-row', function(){
    if($(this).is('[readonly]')) {
         alert('This is not added by you');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Sorry, Writing code on mobile device is not terrific. Please see my updated answer